# Regular expression [:digit:] and [[:digit]] difference

Tags: regex, grep

I am currently learning regular expression. I met a problem that I can't find answer on stackoverflow and I hope someone can help find the answer.

I use vim in mac OS system and vim shows the line.
If the file "regular_expression.txt" is:

```
"Open Source" is a good mechanism to develop programs.
You are the No. 1.
```

Then

```
grep -n '[:lower:]' regular_expression.txt
```

will return

```
1:"Open Source" is a good mechanism to develop programs.

2:You are the No. 1.
```

The command

```
grep '[[:lower:]]' regular_expression.txt
```

will return

```
2:You are the No. 1.
```

I can't understand the above difference because it seems to me that [:lower:] is a set of lower characters. [[:lower:]] should be the same as [:lower:]. It is also confusing that in the first case where [:lower:] is used, all the lines in the file are returned.

Comment: On my linux machine console result is different `grep '[:lower:]'` prints `grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]`. And `grep -n '[[:lower:]]'` returns two strings `1:"Open Source" is a good mechanism to develop programs.
2:You are the No. 1.` But I don't understand how vim is related to this question

Comment: If the  posix class `[:lower:]` is not wrapped in square brackets, the regex parser has no way of knowing it is not a class of characters. Btw, grep is going to return true if it finds a single character that matches the regex in this case. I think that the second use of `grep [:lower:]` has no -n option (whatever that is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX character classes must be wrapped in bracket expressions.

The `[:lower:]` pattern is a positive bracket expression that matches a single char, `:`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `e` or `r`.

The `[[:lower:]]` pattern is a positive bracket expression that matches any char that is matched with the `[:lower:]` POSIX character class (that matches any lowercase letters).

See [`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> certain named classes of characters are predefined **within bracket expressions**... Note that the brackets in these class names are part of the symbolic names, and must be included in addition to the brackets delimiting the bracket expression.
>
> If you mistakenly omit the outer brackets, and search for say, `[:upper:]`, GNU grep prints a diagnostic and exits with status 2, on the assumption that you did not intend to search for the nominally equivalent regular expression: `[:epru]`.

Comment: I see the issue, Thanks!

Comment: @LAWRENCE The `[^[:lower:]]` pattern represents a negated bracket expression, inside which the `[:lower:]` sequence is parsed as a POSIX character class, and it matches any char but a lowercase letter.

Comment: @LAWRENCE Any feedback? `[...]` and `[^...]` are both *bracket expressions* and my answer covers both `[[:lower:]]` and `[^[:lower:]]`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Yes you are right. It is a negated bracket expression.